# How can I embed <!--[if lt IE 9]> tags into Blaze.Html5-generated HTML?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haskell, comments, blaze-html

I'm trying to output the minimal template for Twitter Bootstrap using the `Text.Blaze.Html5` module, but it has comments like the following which I don't know how to include in the Blaze output (I can't see any 'comment' functions in `Text.Blaze.Html5`):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

(from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

How should I go about generating such code?

The docs here http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/docs/Text-Blaze-Html5.html don't provide any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preEscapedText` from `Text.Blaze.Internal`.
Here is an example, adapted from [the starter kit](https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty-starter/blob/master/Views/Home.hs):

```
import Text.Blaze.Html5 (docTypeHtml)
import Views.Utils (pet) -- `pet` is an alias for `preEscapedText`

layout t b = docTypeHtml $ do
       pet "<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7'> <![endif]-->"
       pet "<!--[if IE 7]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8'/> <![endif]-->"
       pet "<!--[if IE 8]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9'> <![endif]-->"
       pet "<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class='no-js'> <!--<![endif]-->"
```

Comment: An example would be better than a link